# Set an ENUM with setPropertyActionListener

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I'm trying to set a enum property with setPropertyActionListener but I'm not sure how to do it. Here's the entity:

```
@Entity
public class Invoice {
    public enum InvoiceStatus { ACTIVE, CANCELED }

        ...

        @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private InvoiceStatus status;

        ...

        public InvoiceStatus getStatus() {
        return status;
    }


    public void setStatus(InvoiceStatus status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
```

And here's the command button which is suppose to set the status to ACTIVE with setPropertyActionListener

```
   ...

  <h:form id="invoiceCreatedSuccessfully">
        <p:dialog header="#{msg['title.success']}" widgetVar="invoiceCreatedSuccessfullyDialog" resizable="false" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade">  
            <h:panelGrid columns="2" rows="3" style="margin-bottom: 10px">  
                <h:outputText value="#{msg['message.invoiceCreatedSuccessfully']}" />
            </h:panelGrid>  
            <p:commandButton value="#{msg['label.acknowledged']}" actionListener="#{invoiceManager.reload}" action="viewInvoices">
                <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{invoiceManager.invoice.status}" value="ACTIVE" />
            </p:commandButton>
        </p:dialog>
    </h:form>
```

No errors are reported but the field 'status' in the DB is not being set. Can someone tell me why?

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Strings are not directly converted to Enums in EL , you would need to a custom converted in your **faces-config** , jsf has one enum converter that should work for you,</strike>

```
<converter>
  <converter-for-class>java.lang.Enum</converter-for-class>
  <converter-class>javax.faces.convert.EnumConverter</converter-class>
</converter>
```

Now looking into the source code of EnumConverter , it seems like it works only if targetClass is available in converter.

So you would need to extend it to work with your enum ,

```
public class MyEnumConverter extends EnumConverter {
  public MyEnumConverter () {
    super(MyEnum.class);
  }
}

<converter>
  <converter-id>MyEnum</converter-id>
  <converter-class>com.test.MyEnumConverter</converter-class>
</converter>
```

add `<f:converter converterId="MyEnum"/>` in your component.

If you have many Enums and to make things easy , you can have a look into omnifaces http://showcase.omnifaces.org/converters/GenericEnumConverter